# Format issue at run time in OBIEE11G

Tags: obiee

I want my cell size to be static at runtime regardless of default images, which I kept in each cell of the analysis. The problem is, I have kept an default image in each cell ,when it runs the cell's width gets enlarged automatically. Please suggest me what can be done, to keep the cell size static at run time,Cell size should not get enlarged at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) It's an "analysis" and not a "report". A "report" is a completely different object type: a BI Publisher report.
b) Therein already lies your answer: Oracle provides the two distinct tools of Answers and BI Publisher because the first is used for analytical, dynamic rendering and the second for pixel-perfect, more static reporting.
c) To sum up: OBI Answers = dynamic. BIP = pixel perfect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but I am not using BIP It can be done only on OBI. Is there any ways to keep my cell size static in OBI ?

Comment: No. Look at how things are rendered. It's all tds and trs inheriting sizing from the - for a pivot for example - dynamically created OOLT element.

Once more: It's dynamic HTML. This isn't Excel! If you need pixel-perfect then use BIP.

Comment: No problem. Many times the reason of existence for the two distinct tools is misunderstood or just unknown. Close this question please so other users can see it contains a valid response.